# Define dependencies from hidden jobs in gitlab-CI yaml files?

Tags: dependencies, gitlab-ci, artifact, gitlab-ci.yml

I want to define dependencies to share artifacts from one hidden job to another, so that when I extend a hidden job/use it in a pipeline, I don't need to specify that the job depends on another hidden job's artifacts, e.g.:

```
.foo:
  script:
  - mkdir test/
  - echo "hello-world" > test/foobar.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - test/
.bar:
  script: 
  - do something
  needs:
  - job: .foo
  dependencies:
  - .foo
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - test/

foo-call:
  extends: .foo
  stage: first_stage

baz:
  extends: .bar
  stage: first_stage
  # I should have access to the artifacts produced in foo-call
```

But I haven't had great luck in getting this to work in any capacity, and I largely suspect that any implementation of this would be inorganic.

Are there any obvious options I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't declare hidden jobs as targets of `dependencies:` -- you can only specify concrete (not hidden) jobs that actually exist in the pipeline. This means that you often can't reasonably/meaningfully create hidden job templates that declare `dependencies:` in advance -- the dependencies will need to be declared with the concrete jobs. The same goes for `needs:`.

One alternative would be to require the concrete jobs to be in different ordered stages. Then `depedenceis:` can be left blank and artifacts to download will be implied by the stage ordering.

Additionally, `needs:` implies `dependencies:` so you only have to define `needs:` in this case.

So remove `needs:`/`dependencies:` from the hidden jobs:

```yaml
.foo:
  script:
  - mkdir test/
  - echo "hello-world" > test/foobar.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - test/

.bar:
  script: 
  - do something
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - test/
```

And declare `needs:` for the actual jobs:

```yaml
foo-call:
  extends: .foo
  stage: first_stage

baz:
  extends: .bar
  stage: first_stage
  needs: [foo-call]
```

Or use different stages without `needs:`/`dependencies:`:

```yaml
foo-call:
  extends: .foo
  stage: first_stage

baz:
  extends: .bar
  stage: second_stage
```

Comment: Thanks, I likewise appreciate the tip wrt needs/dependencies. It seems that you're implying, as a general practice, that it would be better to segregate jobs with implicated dependencies via rules + staging, to remove the necessity for explicit dependency specification when using hidden jobs/templates?

Comment: @CaffeineDependent it depends; I probably wouldn't suggest it as a _general_ rule. It can be better in cases where the templated hidden jobs are imported by users and 'instantiated' multiple times by the user. It reduces the potential for misconfiguration IME. Though, you may run into cases where you _must_ have a `needs:` or `dependencies:` configuration, such as to avoid collisions of the same artifact paths between jobs. You may also want to specify these keys to avoid downloading more artifacts than necessary...